# "Choice" Site Column Shows Blank Options In Some SharePoint Lists But Not Others

Tags: site-column, choices

I've got a site column, which is a "Choice" type, which has a list of projects. When I add the column to some lists it works fine and displays the projects as expected. However in other lists the column doesn't list the project names, all of the choices are blank circles. If you start to type into the field it does seem to filter down to the specific project but never displays the name. Below is an example of what it looks like. Has anyone seen this before? I've tried to open up the "column formatting" JSON in a working list and compare to the JSON in a broken list but they are the exact same. Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: Do you have any sort of column formatting applied specific to that field? Looks like that could be possible reason of something specified is not rendering correctly at front end with the code specified in `Column formatting`. 

Simply try to remove column formatting and see if it works.